# Google position sharing (permanently) from Secondary Android User - Fails - Is that possibile? (Motorola Moto G8 Plus - Android 10)

Tags: motorola-moto-g, geolocation, multi-user

We configured two users on our Motorola Moto G8 Plus:  one admin (primary user)  and a one Secondary user.
We usually use the secondary one where we have personal WhatsApp, and google account.
With the personal account, on the secondary user, we have a problem with Google position sharing; In detail I can see the positions of contacts who shared the position with us, and I can also share with them our (secondary user/account) position, BUT only for limited time (you can choose the time, max 1 hr). With the admin user I can share the position permanently, with the secondary user I cannot.

When I try to start, with the secondary user, the Google position sharing settings page (in Andorid Geolocation config, I have an OFF setting on "enable position sharing" (I have the exact name in Italian, this is a fair translation of the field name) it fails with a dialog error: "Cannot start ... "

I already tired:
to disable position share for the admin, primary, user account, but this has not unlocked the setting page on the secondary user.
I also tried disabling completely geolocation for the admin, primary, user account, no changes for the secondary user.

Motorola Moto G8 Plus runs Android 10.

Is there any trick to enable permanent position sharing for the--secondary user--google account?

It seems that the primary, admin user, google account stops updating its position when secondary user is active. In alternative, is there any way to keep updating that?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the secondary user administrator access for direct location value. I would not give my guest user that authorization. A risky patch would be sharing WhatsApp identity if you just require the location. You can Try experimenting with applications that share location abroad and you can share app identity on the device.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but in the scenario where the guest is totally trusted... or the same guy..  For the sake of curiosity: How do I give administrator access to a secondary android user? [I have not seen that option around, do I need developer's settings?], Regards